Loading tiff image using PIL in Python leads to kernel restart
I encounter a problem for loading tiff images using PIL in Python. I downloaded the test tiff files from:
https://libtiff.gitlab.io/libtiff/images.html
For example, trying to load "zackthecat.tif" with the following code:
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = np.array(Image.open('zackthecat.tif'))

Absolutly no errors, but soon after I see : Restarting kernel...
I have libtiff installed, as well as imagecodecs
I encounter this issue on Windows 10, Python 3.11.7, IPython 8.20.0.
I tried both spyder and in jupyter notebook. I tried to downgrade libtiff from 4.5.0 to 4.4.0 with no changes.
I tried to load the tiff image using matplotlib (plt.imread), fabio... No success.

did you tried to run it as normal script in console/terminal python.exe script.py ? Maybe it will show more details. And you could show it in question (not in comments) as text (not image).

did you try to load this image in some image viewer? Maybe image is broken.

Thanks @furas : I just tried using python script.py, absolutely no output even by adding print(im) after my previous code.  I just tried to open it, the image loads correctly in the native Windows viewer

it is strange that it show anything. With error message we could try to help but without any messages we have no idea what can makes problem. The only idea: first run code only with Image.open('zackthecat.tif') to see if problem makes pillow or numpy.

Yes, indeed by only doing Image.open('zackthecat.tif') it works, and print(im) returns <PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=I size=3108x3262 at ...> ! But if I run just im in the shell, it crashes!

interestingly using the file pc260001.tif in the test tiff files, it works OK.  Readme mentions that this one has no compression. With this file, adding np.array works and return a ndarray correctly. It must be related to compression or something

I use Linux so I can't help you more. Code works for me for pillow: 10.3.0, numpy: 1.26.4, libtiff: 4.3.0, Python 3.10, without using IPython

documentation for TIFF in pillow mentions problems with some versions of TIFF but in version before 5.0.0

@furas, indeed on my linux it works perfectly too

Here I have pillow 10.2.0, libtiff 4.5.0, numpy 1.26.4 on python3.11. The bug is also present without using IPython.

on my Linux Mint I found command tiffile which shows some information about tiff file and for zackthecat.tif it shows Series 0 failed with ValueError: <COMPRESSION.OJPEG: 6> requires the 'imagecodecs' package and maybe this can make problem with this file.

Thanks, I see. However I have imagecodecs 2023.1.23 installed, and not only zackthecat.tif leads to this bug but most of the test images !

well, I don't have Windows to test it. And code doesn't show any error message which could help to see problem. Usually when code has problem without showing error message (and it makes Restarting kernel.) then problem is somewhere in C/C++ code :/

I wouldn't get too hung up on the samples shipped with libtiff. Many are not supported by PIL anyway:

caspian.tif is 64-bits/sample RGB which PIL doesn't support
off_l16.tif is in LogL colourspace, which is not supported by PIL
off_l24.tif and off_l32.tif are in LogLuv colourspace which is not supported by PIL
cramps_tile.tif is truncated as reported by ImageMagick
text.tif and dscXXXX.tif both have errors anyway

Also, zackthecat.tif is compressed with O_JPEG ("old JPEG") which is a complete mess of a standard and was superseded in 1995 by TechNote 2.
If you really have to process weird and wonderful TIFFs, I would recommend you try tifffile.

Thanks for your answer, I understand that there is no need to process all these strange tif files.  However I believe the problem is deeper as even a = np.zeros((10,10), dtype='uint8') im = Image.fromarray(a) im.save('test.tif', compression="tiff_deflate") leads to the same kernel restart behavior. Same using im.save('test.tif', compression="tiff_adobe_deflate"). Uncompressed works well.

@Alexos you're right, and he's (mostly) wrong - it's a bug that may bite you later and if your work is at all important it matters a great deal. That said, his recommendation is a good one. PIL is trash for anything approaching 'real' work on large sets. pylibtiff is another.
